# How can I get the amount of transferred bytes on asynchronous reading boost asio c++

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous, boost-asio

As I've seen in Boost::asio the async read functions does not return the amount of bytes transferred but normal read functions does. How can I get the amount of bytes transferred when I use async_read_some? (Params: buffer, handler)

Comment: Did you take a look at the docs? This is a very basic information that appears in any socket-related example or function reference http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html

Answer (score 4):

[All forms of `async_read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html) expect a "`ReadHandler`" callback of the form

```
void handler(
  const boost::system::error_code& error, // Result of operation.

  std::size_t bytes_transferred           // Number of bytes copied into the
                                          // buffers. If an error occurred,
                                          // this will be the  number of
                                          // bytes successfully transferred
                                          // prior to the error.
);
```

The second parameter of your callback will be the number of bytes read.

Answer (score 2):

The asynchronous read functions call a "handler" function (or function object) once the read is complete. The number of bytes transferred is passed to that function; the signature of the function must be:

```
void handler(
    const boost::system::error_code& error, // Result of operation.
    std::size_t bytes_transferred           // Number of bytes read.
);
```

The requirements for read handlers are documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html)